# Error when passing data from Twig to Controller

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4

I'm trying to pass some data from my twig to my controller but I'm getting this error

```
No route found for "POST /agent/": Method Not Allowed (Allow: GET)
```

Allow me to explain what I did, I have a list, and each car in this list has a button, I click the button to show a modal form that allows me to create a ticket related to that car.

Presssing that button passes the id and number of the selected car to the form. I was able to render the form without passing anything, but whenever I try passing the id of the car I get the error.

**My code:**
index.html.twig

```
      {% for parking in user.parkings %}

         <table id="file_export" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <tbody>
            {% for car in car %}
                <tr>
                <td>
               {{ car.matricule }}
                </td>
                <td>
              <span class="timer" data-expires="{{ car.getExpiresAt() }}"> 
              </span>

                </td>
             <td>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" href="{{ path('new_amende', {'id': car.id},{'number': car.number}) }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#createmodel" data-whatever="{{ car.id }}">
ticket                                
</button>
            {{render(controller('App\\Controller\\AgentController:newAmende')) }}

                </td>
                </tr>
             {% endfor %}
```

controller

```
    /**
     * @Route("/{id}/new", name="new_ticket", methods={"GET","POST"})
     */
    public function newTicket(Request $request, Car $car): Response
    {
        $ticket = new Ticket();
        $form = $this->createForm(TicketType::class, $ticket);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $this->addFlash('success','ticket added !');

            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($ticket);
            $entityManager->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('agent');


         }

        return $this->render('Agent/modal.html.twig', [
            'ticket' => $ticket,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

**Edit** here's my other controller

```
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="agent", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function index(): Response
    {

        $use = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();

        $user = $this->getUser();   
        $parkingz=$this->getUser()->getParkings();

        return $this->render('Agent/Agent.html.twig', [
            'user' => $user,
            'parkings'=>$parkings,
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the controller with the route /agent ?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to reach /agent using POST, whereas you only allowed GET request on this route `No route found for "POST /agent/": Method Not Allowed (Allow: GET)`.

So modify your index() to allow POST :

```
 /**
 * @Route("/", name="agent", methods={"GET","POST"})
 */
public function index(): Response
{
```

Comment: I don't know if it worked or not because I get an error :  An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request information for parameter "car".").

Comment: Also when I add POST to index, the data stops inserting into the database when I submit the form

Comment: @Hyperion Best to stick with one problem at a time.  This answer got you past the symptom but not the actual issue which is that POST /agent should probably be POST new ticket since the agent route does not actually process a POST request.  In your twig, new_amende should probably be new_ticket.

Comment: maybe you're right, it's just that i've been stuck with this part of the project for days now

Comment: It can be frustrating when starting out.  So many details to learn.  You have stuff like $parkingz vs $parkings which implies that you are not even using an IDE.  Makes life very difficult.  Consider starting a new project with just a ticket entity.  Get the new ticket functionality to work without anything fancy.  Follow the docs as close as possible.  Eventually the pieces will start to fit.  And read about the [fundamentals of http request handling](https://symfony.com/doc/current/introduction/http_fundamentals.html).

Comment: I'll see what I can do, it's a big project and starting from scratch is impossible.

Comment: I agree that starting from scratch is almost always the wrong approach. The problem is that you seems to be struggling (for days) with basic concepts such as the difference between GET and POST and how http routing works.  Creating a new project and implementing a tiny bit of functionality might prove helpful as a learning tool by reducing the complexity of the code you are struggling with.  Or maybe not.